macOS not switching Spaces when opening links from Slack to Firefox
I’m experiencing an issue with macOS where clicking a link in Slack (which I have open in one Space) opens the link in Firefox (which is in another Space), but macOS no longer automatically switches me to the Space with Firefox. Previously, this would work as expected, where clicking a link would take me straight to Firefox’s Space.
I’ve tried restarting both apps, as well as macOS, but the issue persists. I’m wondering if another app or setting might be interfering with this behavior.
"When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for the application" option is turned on.
Thanks!

Welcome to Ask Different. Which macOS is your Mac using? Do you use a stable Firefox release or is it a nightly build? Do you use the latest Slack and Firefox releases? Can you trace back this change in behavior to a macOS or app update? If you configure Safari as your default web browser in macOS (or in the Slack app), do spaces switch as expected?

thanks! I'm running macOS Sonoma with the latest versions of Firefox Developer Edition and Slack. No recent system or application changes come to mind that could be related to the issue. Safari as default browser makes no difference unfortunately

Thank you, that's weird... So the link opens in Firefox (or Safari) but doesn't switch to its space? Do you have multiple displays? Are displays configured to have separate spaces (check System Settings > Desktop & Dock, scroll down to Mission Control)? Are the Slack and Firefox spaces on the same display or on different displays?

possible cause, just got a reply from the slack team: "I'm afraid you've run into a known bug that our engineers are aware of where clicking on an external link does not move focus to the browser."

Good to know, could you post that as an answer? It will help others with a similar issue, thanks!

sure just waiting for confirmation that this is indeed it

I've also run into this issue, and it appears to have nothing to do with Spaces.
I don't use separate spaces.
Firefox is my default browser.
Can reproduce the issue while not using any external displays.
Clicking a link in Slack will open the link in Firefox, but the Firefox window does not gain focus. Slack maintains focus.

slack support said the only working browser is Chrome and that they are working on a fix for all browsers

Slack Version 4.41.98 seems to fix the issue :)
